# What do you call a collection of SQL queries that execute in a row?

Tags: sql, terminology

This seems like a basic question but I was unable to find an answer on Google. If I have a SQL query that creates a temporary table and then another and then another and then another and then finally extracts the results, each one of those operations is a query. But what is the word for all of them together? It’s obviously common to string together a whole bunch of queries to go from a base table to a final output. There must be a word for the group of queries together. It’s not a collection, sequence, or series because all of those words are SQL keywords.

Or perhaps each one of those create-table operations is actually called a statement, and the whole thing together is a query? I know that at my job, they refer to each one as a query.

Comment: It's a query.  It is a complicated query (and it's not common), but it's still a query.

Comment: I would use the term "query" despite the fact that it may contain many steps with various statements used. nb: `select` is a statement, `update` is a statement (`case` is an expression)

Comment: I would call it a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including all of them within the construct of a LUW (logical unit of work), it's a transaction.  Transactions can be simple or complicated, and for lack of a better word this could also be a called a procedure or program when you sequence a number of DML / DDL statements together.

Per Nathan's comment, it could also be referred to as a SQL Script.